# Fetch data from sharepoint list using google apps script community connector

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-community-connector

I have a requirement to use google apps script and fetch data from sharepoint list. I am a database person who works in BigQuery. I am not familiar with JavaScript as apps script uses javaScript. I will need some help to build custom connector. I will need some help particularly in the getconfig section in the apps script section.

I have searched everywhere and there is so little info available.

Kindly help!